# React form onSubmit function not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, post

I have a form on my page with an onSubmit function that I want to be called, but it doesn't seem to be triggered as the console.log never appears.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class EmailSignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
      this.state = {
        email: '',
        lastName: '',
        error: false
      }

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this)
   }

  onSubmitForm (e) {
    console.log('function has run');
    e.preventDefault()
    let formData = new FormData(e)
    const { formAction } = this.props

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    }

    fetch(formAction, requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
  }

  handleChange (e) {
    const value = e.target.value
    const inputId = e.target.id
    this.setState(() => ({
      [inputId]: value
    }))
  }

  render () {
    const { error } = this.state

    return (
      <div id='email-form' className='container'>
          <form
            name='form'
            id='form'
            onSubmit={this.onSubmitForm}
            method='post'
          >
            <div className='form-group'>
              <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
              <input
                type='email'
                name='Email'
                className='form-control'
                id='email'
                placeholder='youremail@email.com'
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.email}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <label htmlFor='lastName'>Last name</label>
              <input
                type='text'
                name='lastName'
                className='text form-control'
                id='lastName'
                placeholder='Last Name'
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.lastName}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <button
              type='submit'
              name='Submit'
              value='Subscribe'
              className='btn btn-primary item_cta'
              readOnly
            />
          </form>
          {error && <p>{error}</p>}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default EmailSignUp
```

Comment: remove `method` from form, also why do you have `readOnly` on the button?

Comment: if I remove the method then it still doesn't run and it goes to the URL with all the form data as a query? like www.test.com?email=&lastname=

Comment: Have you reviewed the errors the console? It's clear that their is an issue with how you are trying to use FormData `Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-et2my9?file=src/Form.js

Answer (score 0):

Running your code results in the error `'Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'`. The actual form element would be on `target` of the submit event. Try the following by updating `e` to `e.target`:

```
let formData = new FormData(e.target);
const { formAction } = this.props;
```

Also remove `method` from the `form` element. In addition, remove `readOnly` from `button`. It is not meant to be a self closing element like a `br`:

```
<button
  type="submit"
  name="Submit"
  value="Subscribe"
  className="btn btn-primary item_cta"
 >submit</button>
```

Hopefully that helps!